# What is the format of the private key required to deploy using deploy-zksync?

Tags: contract-deployment, private-key, hardhat-deploy, zksync

I am trying to deploy a very basic smart contract using `zkSync`. This is the code, from they docs:

**deploy.ts**

```
import { Wallet, utils } from "zksync-web3";
import * as ethers from "ethers";
import { HardhatRuntimeEnvironment } from "hardhat/types";
import { Deployer } from "@matterlabs/hardhat-zksync-deploy";
import { mnemonic } from "../.secrets.json";
// An example of a deploy script that will deploy and call a simple contract.
export default async function (hre: HardhatRuntimeEnvironment) {
  console.log(`Running deploy script for the Greeter contract`);
  // Initialize the wallet.
  const wallet = new Wallet("<WALLET-PRIVATE-KEY>");
  // Create deployer object and load the artifact of the contract you want to deploy.
  const deployer = new Deployer(hre, wallet);
  const artifact = await deployer.loadArtifact("Greeter");
  // Estimate contract deployment fee
  const greeting = "Hi there!";
  const deploymentFee = await deployer.estimateDeployFee(artifact, [greeting]);
  // OPTIONAL: Deposit funds to L2
  // Comment this block if you already have funds on zkSync.
  const depositHandle = await deployer.zkWallet.deposit({
    to: deployer.zkWallet.address,
    token: utils.ETH_ADDRESS,
    amount: deploymentFee.mul(2),
  });
  // Wait until the deposit is processed on zkSync
  await depositHandle.wait();
  // Deploy this contract. The returned object will be of a `Contract` type, similarly to ones in `ethers`.
  // `greeting` is an argument for contract constructor.
  const parsedFee = ethers.utils.formatEther(deploymentFee.toString());
  console.log(`The deployment is estimated to cost ${parsedFee} ETH`);
  const greeterContract = await deployer.deploy(artifact, [greeting]);
  //obtain the Constructor Arguments
  console.log("constructor args:" + greeterContract.interface.encodeDeploy([greeting]));
  // Show the contract info.
  const contractAddress = greeterContract.address;
  console.log(`${artifact.contractName} was deployed to ${contractAddress}`);
}
```

They say to replace `"<WALLET-PRIVATE-KEY>"` with the private key of the wallet I want to use for development.

What is the format I should use for that `PK`?

If I use the `mnemonic` I get this error:

```
Error: invalid hexlify value (argument="value", value="xyz", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bytes/5.7.0)
```

If I use the private key you get from `metamask`, I get this error:

```
Error: Bytecode length in 32-byte words must be odd
```

What is it the actual format of this `PK`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a private key, a mnemonic phrase etc. All methods supported by ethers are also supported by `zksync-web3`. Here is more info in [the ethers documentation](https://v2-docs.zksync.io/api/js/accounts.html#other-ways-to-create-wallet-instances).

If you have a metamask account, you can [export the private key following this guide](https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015289632-How-to-export-an-account-s-private-key).

Just make sure you're using a different account only for development and never push your private key to any repositories.